# Maxima and minima of partial derivatives

Tags: derivatives

I'm currently on the topic of finding maxima/minima for partial derivatives.

However, I've recently come across a question which is rather confusing.

Given: $$f(x,y) = x^3 -y^2 + 3x  for  (x,y) R^2 $$

I've calculated the Hessian matrix and retrieved $$-12x$$ I can also take the first partial derivative of x and y.

BUT, when I try to put the partial derivatives equal to zero, my value for x is imaginary. Is there a possible solution to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Are you sure a maximum or minimum exists?

Comment: It is $\nabla f=(3x^2+3,-2y)\ne (0,0),\forall (x,y).$ Since $f$ is differentiable you can say that there is no local maximum/minimum. On the other hand, to study extrema you have to consider the Hessian matrix, not only its determinant.

Comment: No. But how does one prove that?

Comment: @Yankee How does one prove what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3x$ and we get $f_x=3x^2+3\geq 3\ne 0$ thus we get no local extrema.

Comment: Just to clarify, does that mean that there aren't any critical points?

Comment: A saddle point is a critical point, but by proving that there are no maxima/minima is that by extension proving no saddle points?

Comment: Hi @Dr.Sonnhard , 
I'm trying to prove an identity using Lagrange multipliers and standard vector equations. I'd be very grateful if you even had a hint to point me in the right direction http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034055/lagrange-identity